# Is it a good practice to put promo videos in github source

Tags: git, github

I have some materials like screenshots, promo graphics, video, etc as part of my project. The promo video is made with Adobe Premiere and I want to back up the video for future use. Is it acceptable practice on GitHub to include all the promo graphics and videos as part of my project on that site? The promo video is really large and this will make the git source really huge and I'm afraid this will somehow badly affect my source code quality. What are the rules/factors that I must consider?

Comment: I think it's a primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: To downvoters: rather than downvote, flag as close because "opinion-based".

Comment: I wouldn't recommend adding such a large file to your git repo. Perhaps hosting the file on a dedicated file hosting solution and simply adding the link to the file in your repo's readme file would be a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think not. Github's own help documentation has some things to say about large things not actually part of the source, see, for example: [what-is-my-disk-quota](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/) and [working-with-large-files](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/). Don't forget that a Git repository will store previous versions of changed files which is going to eat large chunks of storage space if you do modify that video.  Also as that second help article states

> "GitHub will warn you when pushing files larger than 50 MB. You will not be allowed to push files larger than 100 MB."

Is it feasible to store the binary resources elsewhere, e.g. Dropbox for example, and link to those?

Answer (score 0):

Git recommends to not include large files, be it binary or otherwise (database, etc) in a source repository.

See this Git help page that will tell more about the downsides of including large files in Git:

[Working with large files in git](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-large-files/)

"A Git repository contains every version of every file. But for some file types, this is not practical. Multiple revisions of large files increase the clone and fetch times for other users of a repository. "

Instead, I would recommend using Git LFS for storage of large files:

[Git-LFS](https://github.com/github/git-lfs)